Angular v17 : Micro Frontends using standalone component bootstrapApplication to load into a shell container
I'm using Angular v17. I have a shell container Angular app and a new standalone Angular component app. I'm trying to use createCustomElement and customElements.define for the standalone component.
I've bundled the bundle.js (dist/polly.js, dist/main.js) file and loaded it(test-mfe.js) into the shell container app.
app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss'
})
export class AppComponent {

}

main.ts
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
import { createApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { appConfig } from './app/app.config';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';

createApplication(appConfig).then((app) => { 
  if (!customElements.get('test-mfe')) {
    const mfeElement = createCustomElement(AppComponent, {injector: app.injector});
    customElements.define('test-mfe', mfeElement);
  }
}).catch((err) => {  
  console.error(err);
});

It works fine with the development build, but the production build throws an error and the element doesn't load.
Error:
TypeError: re is not a function
    at Yo (test-mfe.js:10:6770)
    at test-mfe.js:10:6590
    at test-mfe.js:10:127
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mi (test-mfe.js:10:91)
    at test-mfe.js:10:119
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Mi (test-mfe.js:10:91)
    at $u (test-mfe.js:10:6573)
    at Vf (test-mfe.js:10:6476)

all other configuration like tsconfig.json, angular.json etc same as angular v17 generated apps.
The error message is not very clear. Could you please help me understand and resolve this issue?
Thanks!

it feels like the error is rather happening somewhere in the code, but not in the place you are showing here. I would try to build prod build but with source maps to see where exactly the error is happening

source Map=true also same error doesn't help.

This is likely due to concatenating the separate files into one module.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/56517
any suggestion on this how build standalone as bundle.js file?
